# how to get week average from month in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, average

i have day, month, year, value columns in one table, here i need to get every week average value in one month.
how to get that. please help me regarding this.

```
select avg(value) from table group by month
```

gives month average.

```
select avg(value) from table group by day
```

gives day average.
but how to get week average from month field.

Comment: Can you post some sample data...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "get weeks from a month" as one is not a subset of the other.
The number of days (and hence weeks) in 1 month varies from month to month and only in non-leap years - and in February only - are there exactly 4 weeks in a month.

You should use the original date field and use a date function to limit/group the data by week.
get the week in mySQL with
`WEEK(timestamp)`
or
`YEARWEEK(timestamp)`
or
`WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())`
or
`DATE_FORMAT($yourDate, \'%X %V\') as week`

Comment: @RameshK, Michael is correct.  some month's may start on say.. Tue, Wed or Thu.  So that leaves a half/week at the beginning and possibly at the end too.  Look at Feb 2012... 5 weeks total, first and last partial.  How would that accurately portray an "average"...

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but my first thought is to write a query that calculates the week of the year for each day and groups them. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear

Something like:

```
SELECT avg(value) FROM table GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(CONCAT(year, '-', month, '-', day))
```